# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'classRoomId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 I have a action method in studentController which filter students by classroomId

    public ActionResult ClassStudents(int classRoomId)
    {

        var students = st.GetAll().Where(s => s.ClassRoomID == classRoomId);

        var classroom = clr.GetByID(classRoomId);

        ViewBag.ClassRoomTitle = classroom.ClassRoomTitle;

        return View(students);
    }




when i input  /Student/ClassStudents/1

it give me a error as:
```

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'classRoomId' of 
   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult 
 ClassStudents(Int32)'

Can you find whats the problem?
thanks

Comment: Is the 1 in the url intended to be the classroomid? If so you need to configure a route for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter" - How to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500021/the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public ActionResult ClassStudents(int ClassRoomId)
```

to

```
public ActionResult ClassStudents(int? ClassRoomId)
```

That will make ClassRoomId **nullable**

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
int classRoomId
```

with either

```
int? classRoomId
```

if you want to handle nulls or with

```
int classRoomId = 0
```

if you want to have a default value instead of null.